# Unity. Which is faster: one big script with switch(ObjectType) or lot of simple scripts?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, unity-game-engine

Unity3d. Mobile.
Runner game. There are some types of objects, like cars, BG, scenes, food, obstacles, powerUps and so on. And actions, which can be used or not by different objects. 
From start - I was doing lot of different scripts like "`sizeChanger`" or "`Sprite flipper`", almoust all of them are using different `2D colliders`, some of them are tracking `Player position.x`.

**Problem** was in situation, where some actions in activity are repeating actions like tracking `Player position.x`.

So I've made one flexible script, which has public `enum ObjectType`, where in Awake, Start, Update, OnTriggerEnter2D, OnTriggerExit2D there are switch(ObjectType) ... And as a result at my scene a lot of `gameObjects` with the **same** script with different `ObjectType` statement.

Is that will work slower or difference in performance is not worth to wory about? *(As a little problem I have no backup to test FPS at an old version with a lot of scripts.)*

Comment: As an opinion, normally smaller scripts will be more suitable for me since long scripts mean harder to check. But this is only IMO.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, but putting everything in one script, copy pasting and switching between behavior depending on your ObjectType is a bad idea.

Comment: Why don't you test and find out?  You not having the old version is not an excuse, as neither do we.  So, if you really want to know, test both scenarios.

Comment: hi Dmitriy ... there is no difference.  (Or only a very small difference.)

Comment: suggest you "tick" your own answer (it's OK to do that) to help keep the board tidy, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I've Added 1200 Objects to a start scene And at firts start(right Profiler) there were working separate small scripts, at second start(left Prifiler) was working big script...

Result:

- Some simple scripts - 23.03ms (standalone) latency
- Large script - 23.6ms (standalone) latency
  [image: Standalone Profiler]

Result:

- Some simple scripts - 63ms(android) latency
- Large script - 67ms (android) latency
  [image: Android Profiler]

Difference is 4ms at 1200Objects.

For my game As I see - difference in performance is not the reason to wory about, because at my game scene there will be maximum 50 objects.